# Python misinterpret KeyboardInterrupt exception when using Lingoes

Tags: python, unix, keyboardinterrupt

I want to write a python program (run.py) that always runs and only stops running when Ctr-C is pressed. This is how I implement it:

wrapper.py:

```
import subprocess
import signal
 
def sig_handler(signum, frame):
    res = input("Ctrl-c was pressed. Do you really want to exit? y/n ")
    if res == 'y':
        exit(1)
 
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, sig_handler)

while(True):
    p = None
    p = subprocess.Popen("python run.py", shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

run.py:

```
print('aaaaa')
print('bbbbb')
```

However, when I hold left-mouse and select text in the terminal that is running wrapper.py, this event is understood incorrectly as Ctr-C then the wrapper.py stop running run.py. My question is how to prevent reading mouse events as KeyboardInterrupt in python (Unix). Thanks!

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG4Vz.png)

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: I use Terminator. I tried to find the configuration that disables mouse event but not found. I also tested with default terminal of Ubuntu and the result is the same

Comment: Actually, there is no problem with the source code. The problem is the dictionary software. The software has as feature of selecting word to translate. When I select some word, by some way the software converts mouse event to Ctr-C then my program exits. When I turn off the software, the problem disappears

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a module like `signal` to achieve this you could opt to use exceptions since it is a pretty exceptional case that your program will receive a keyboard interrupt.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def main() -> int:
    try:
        while True:
            print(sys.argv)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}', file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code has no problem. The problem is caused by dictionary software. The software has a feature of selecting word to translate. By somehow it converts the mouse event (selecting word) to Ctr-C then the program above exits. When I turn off the dictionary software, the problem disappears. I will close the thread here

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include information about the dictionary software used so other people can search for the solution in the future

Comment: The software is Lingoes

Comment: Consider updating the question a little to reflect the problem you had and then accepting this answer